# Locate workflow Service Application Proxy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Where can I find "I workflow Service Application Proxy" in central admin?

http://www.datazx.cn/Forums/en-US/7675ea81-457d-4491-a224-e34471beec63/action?threadDisplayName=sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager-not-connected&forum=sharepointcustomization

Answer (score 0):

Open the central admin, click the manage service application.

In the service application you can see the "Workflow service application proxy". This workflow service application is created by default.

"I workflow service application proxy" is created by that man.